# SerialPort.ReadTo getting data when doing Step Over, but not on normal execution

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I'm building a WPF app that has to communicate through a Serial Port. When I send some data to the serial port it is supposed to reply with some data. For example, I send a PIG\r\n and it reply with ACK\r\n. During a normal execution of the code, I send a command to get me some data from a third device connect to the second (which is attached to my serial port) I don't get any reply, only a timeout exception. However, when I try to debug the code (using step over) it works as expected.

I have try to do Step over short than the Timeout (30s) and still gets the problem.
I have create a console application to test my code and it works fine on it. So, I'm assume there are some problems on WPF, But I don't know where to look.

My Read function

```
public ComandoFactory Ler()
{
    try
    {
        string Mensagem = sp.ReadTo("\r\n");
        var comando = new ComandoFactory(Mensagem.Substring(0,3), Mensagem.Substring(3));
        return comando;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        return new ComandoFactory("ERR", "TIMEOUT");
    }
    catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        return new ComandoFactory("ERR", "ARGUMENT");
    }
}
```

ReadTo should return something, instead of giving a Timeout.

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: I'm not a big fan of `ReadTo`, it seems to give a lot of people problems.  Mostly because it's blocking until it sees the characters you are looking for.  Is using the `DataReceived` event an option?  I would recommend using soemthing like this and building your own string until you see a `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a small wait between the Write and read operation. 100 ms did the trick and the code is working now. However, I know this is not the best solution. @Baddack idea of using DataReceived is probably better and I'll try when I can.